# How to import partials in other partial in Laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to import partial template in other partial.
For example, I'm already using header partial.

Current Structure is

```html
-- header.blade.php
--+ partials
  |__ nave.blade.php
```

In this case, I want to use nav partial in header partial.

But I was not available to add nav to header. I could see not found error.

Is there any special way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please show full path to the view including file name and show how exactly are you trying to import it.

Comment: Make sure you're giving the *full* path to the partial, from the `views` root. You can't reference it on a relative basis.

Comment: Just use `@include` on the blade template. Using the relative path there is fine, using the dot syntax just like when you're creating the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a main.blade.php page.
The content is like this:

```
@include('layouts.header')
<section> Main Content {{$slot}} </section>
@include('layouts.footer')
```

In header.blade.php, here is your content:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="app">  
@include('layouts.nav')
```

On your nav.blade.php page, here could be your content:

```
<nav id="navbar"> Nav Item </nav>
```

Then finally, in your footer partial, you can close the opened divs up:

```
</div>{{--  Closes the #app id  --}}
</div>  {{--  Closes the Container class  --}} 
<script>Your JS links and sources</script>
```

So, in essence, what all these suggest is that within any file, if you call the file path correctly, you can use and

embed any partial from anywhere. Note, the (dot) indentation suggests a level deep down in the files structure.
Which means, in your Views folder, this will be the structure of your subfolders:

```
- Views
   - layouts.blade.php
      - header.blade.php
      - nav.blade.php
      - footer.blade.php
   - home.blade.php
```